# Android Studio install folder? delete to save disc space

Tags: android, windows, file, android-studio

in my Windows users Folder I have found some Folder named

.Android Studio1.2
.Android Studio1.3
.Android Studio1.4
.Android Studio1.5

Can I delete them?

Comment: Not the one which has current version. I guess your current version is 1.5, so other folders you can delete. It saved all your preferences and settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can delete the old folders besides the most recent one (which in your case would seem to be .AndroidStudio1.5). Those folders contain saved preferences and cache files, and is only be needed if you were still running the older versions or needing to migrate settings from one version to the next.

Comment: What about `.AndroidStudio` and `.AndroidStudioBeta` In my case both those folders seem to have been last updated in 2014. They look safe to remove but are an order of magnitude larger than the other folders. (almost 3GB compared to 400-500mb) Are files from here reused in other folders? Thanks!

Comment: What release are you on? To check your release, go to Help > About.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete settings folder of previous version of AS named such as `.AndroidStudioxxx`  in Users folder (in the case for Windows)

[image]